# how fetch kml google earth api

Tags: kml, fetch, google-earth-plugin

My fetch kml does not work. Here is my code:

```
function initCallback(object) {
  ge = object;
  ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);
  function finished(object) {
    if (!object) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        alert('Bad or null KML.');
      }, 0);
      return;
    }
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(object);
  }       

  var url = 'http://localhost/ta/bangun.aula.kml';
  google.earth.fetchKml(ge, url, finished);

  document.getElementById('installed-plugin-version').innerHTML = ge.getPluginVersion().toString();
}
```

Comment: Describe "does not work". What do you see? What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

KML file is not directly parsed by js in your browser.
Google needs to access your KML file.
So you need to place KML file where Google can access it (host online).
Since your KML file is on localhost , Google is not able to access it.